# A little bit confused with this javascript syntax --> arr.indexOf(searchElement[, fromIndex])

Tags: javascript, arrays, indexof

```
   const beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison'];

console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison'));
// expected output: 1

// start from index 2
console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison', 2));
// expected output: 4

console.log(beasts.indexOf('giraffe'));
// expected output: -1
```

I've been repeatedly looking at this js syntax. I've got this code from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf
It says that the fromIndex parameter is the index to start the search at. Now, from the code above, I'm confused about how the counting from the fromIndex parameter happens. From the code on the line:

```
// start from index 2
console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison', 2));
// expected output: 4
```

Camel is the item with index 2. How does the counting happen to arrive with an expected output of 4?

When I try to change the 2nd parameter,

```
// start from index 3
console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison', 3));
```

Duck is the item with index of 3. But the output that comes for indexOf('bison', 3) is still 4.

How does the counting really happen?

Comment: *"Camel is the item with index 2. How does the counting happen to arrive with an expected output of 4?"* Because you've searched for bison : `beasts.indexOf('bison', 2)`

Comment: The second parameter is used as **starting** position for the search. If you want to know if at index `i` there is the string `search`, you can use `if (arr[i] === search) {  }`

Comment: The answer you are getting is an index no. of the value you search and if the value is not found it would return -1. The second argument it takes is a `formIndex`. It starts the search starting from the index provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing gets counted here, it just outputs you the index where the element is at.

If you type in `console.log(beasts.indexOf('bison', 3));`  then you start your search from index 3. You will still get 4 because `bison` is at index 4. Even the name `indexOf` says that you receive the index.

The array stays the same, just the starting point is moved to index 3

```
const beasts = ['ant', 'bison', 'camel', 'duck', 'bison'];
                                            ^
                                            |
                                            |
                    You start here and search to the right for "bison"
```

Comment: makes sense. it's now clear. i thought earlier that the the new starting point becomes index 0.

Answer (score 0):

Very simple.

First element index is 0:

```
> console.log(beasts[0])
"ant"
```

`indexOf` will loop your array if you pass the second parameter.
In other words, if element was not found from the index you pass till its end, the command will continue looking for it from its beginning, continuing the counting.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a matter of counting here. It's all about the position of an element in a zero-index based array.

Maybe you get confused because you get for the same word (`bison`) two indexes. No worry. Don't forget that that word is repeated twice in the array. Without even using `indexOf` you can see that it is in index `1` and index `4`.